# Is it possible to set debug sources for release build type?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

On our project we have a build type for testing, which fallbacks to release:

```
 releaseTesting {
     matchingFallbacks = ['release']
     ...
 }
```

We want to add a debug panel to simplify testing and there is a contradiction, because debug panel module should use debug sources, but it a release type. I tried to add `releaseTesting` build type for a debug panel mdoule and set sources to debug like this:

```
   buildTypes {
       releaseTesting {
          matchingFallbacks = ['release']
       }
   }

   sourceSets {
        releaseTesting {
            setRoot 'src/debug'
        }
    }
```

but it breaks retrieving resources in core modules on which debug panel depends. Is it possible to solve the problem somehow? Or maybe there is a better approach to organize it?

Comment: The whole point of "test on release" is to get 100% accurate representation of what your users are getting. If you're testing with a test panel, it already isn't an accurate release representation. So there is no reason to insist on release for simplified testing anymore. Keep 2 test builds: accurate and simplified, but you need very good discipline because simplified are not real tests, just a quick peek. In my experience, people are lazy and will always substitute simplified for the real thing and this will quietly remove your tests while pretending you still have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best approach I fount is to create no-op implementation and provide it for release build type:

```
debugImplementation(project(":debug:impl"))
releaseTestingImplementation(project(":debug:impl"))
releaseImplementation(project(":debug:no-op"))
```